# Como redirecionar para uma url usando parametros de url

Tags: javascript, url

Gostaria de pegar uma url que se encontra logo após `red=` e redirecionar para ela, caso esteja em branco não redirecionar. Eu usei `window.location.replace("")` apenas para testar o código.
 
**Exemplo de onde quero chegar:** `red=http://www.google.com/`
*O código tem a função de substituir o conteúdo dentro de um elemento, e redirecionar a pagina em alguns segundos.*

```js
window.onload = function substituir() {

   var url = new URL(window.location);
   var sub = url.searchParams.get("sub");
   var red = url.searchParams.get("red");
   setTimeout(redirecionar, 5000);

   if(sub == 1) {
       document.getElementById("subst").innerHTML = "<p>Alguma coisa</p>"
   }

   function redirecionar() {

      if(red == 1) {
         window.location.replace("https://www.google.com");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta verificar se a variável possui valor com `if(variável)` e redirecionar com `window.location.href`.

O valor em `sub` também será enviado para o elemento se ele não for indefinido e não for *null*.

```
window.onload = function substituir() {

   var url = new URL(window.location);
   var sub = url.searchParams.get("sub");
   var red = url.searchParams.get("red");
   setTimeout(redirecionar, 5000);

   if(sub) {
       document.getElementById("subst").innerHTML = "<p>"+sub+"</p>"
   }

   function redirecionar() {

      if(red) {
         window.location.href = red;
      }
   }
}
```

Se o `http://` estiver faltando você pode verificar usando uma regex com `.test()` e concatenar ao valor de `red`:

```
if(red) {
   if(!/^http:\/\//.test(red)){
      red = "http://"+red;
   }
   window.location.href = red;
}
```

A regex `/^http:\/\//` verifica se no início da string possui `http://`.

Comment: Interessante enviar o valor em `sub` para o elemento, porém o problema de redirecionamento caso a url não contenha `http`, atrapalharia caso fosse um `ftp` ou um url magnético por exemplo

Comment: Tudo bem eu vou tentar achar uma solução, obrigado.

Comment: Seria mais viável se o redirecionamento funcionasse com qualquer tipo de url exemplos: `exemplo.com` `www.exemplo.com` `http://www.exemplo.com` `ftp://` `magnet:`

Comment: Sim, mas como vou saber qual o protocolo do link? Se é http, ftp etc

Comment: É possivél faze-lo redirecionar para qualquer coisa? exemplo: `red=algumacoisa` sem que ele redirecione como uma pagina do site, ignorando assim tudo o que vier antes: `http://www.exemplo.com/?sub=1&red=` `algumcoisa`

Comment: Pode redirecionar pra onde vc quiser, desde que vc defina pra onde. Agora, "qualquer coisa" não existe. Imagine vc chegar numa farmácia pra comprar e falar: "me dá qualquer coisa"... não faz sentido.

Comment: sim eu imaginei que não fosse possível, só queria tirar a duvida mesmo, mas enfim, seria interessante se caso houver `ftp://` `magnet:`  não aplicasse a regex `/^http:\/\//`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80744/discussion-between-sam-and-mark-vaaz).

Answer (score 1):

**Código**

```
 $().ready(function () {

    var url = new URL(window.location);
    var sub = url.searchParams.get("sub");
    var red = url.searchParams.get("red");
    setTimeout(redirecionar, 5000);

    if(sub == 1) {
       document.getElementById("subst").innerHTML = "<p>Alguma coisa</p>"
    }

    function redirecionar() {
      if (red.length > 0)
        window.location.replace(red);
    }

  })
```

**Explicação**

A diferença para o seu código é que alterei a condição para o redirecionamento da página. Na nova condição é verificado se o tamanho da `string` capturada pelo parâmetro `red` é maior que `0`.